# Masking in properties file

Tags: java, properties, masking

I came across unfamiliar codes in a properties file

```
SampleData.DefaultValue=$Masking(Head=8,Rear=0,Flag=, Bit=0){ID}
```

Can someone explain me what this does?

In my own understanding, it gets the first 8 digits/characters of ID , for Rear I dont know , for flag and bit. Thanks

Comment: best thing you can do is to see if/how it is used in the code

Answer (score 0):

In sampledata class/method there is a defaultvalue for which this is passing.
Basically property files are used to create one constant variable then you can use that constants by using properties class